# Organic Groups API?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, organic-groups

Where within the realm of Organic Groups (D6) can I find a few functions that do the following:

- Retrieve a list of all Groups
- Retrieve a list of Features for each Group (when iterating Groups)
- Grab links for Groups & Features, checked against menu access for current user

I am looking through the code, but not really seeing what I am looking for- or maybe I saw it and didn't realize it.

I am trying to build a custom navigation based on Groups and want to construct my own menu structure instead of have all groups, and all said groups features, be in a Drupal managed menu (upwards of possibly 20 groups, a lot to manage).

Answer (score 0):

[og_all_groups_options()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--og--og.module/function/og_all_groups_options/6) will get you a list of all the groups. I think the features info is held in the `og_features` table in the `settings` column so you could get the data using the group node's `nid` in each of your loop's iterations

You can use the [l function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6) to build up your link with an access check using  like this:

```
if (og_is_group_member($group->gid)) {
  $link = l($group->title, "node/nid");
}
```

Hope that helps